# Get the tree node by its nodeid

Tags: extjs

If tree is not expanded am not able to get node of a tree.
am using like this.
    tree.getNodeById(id);

thanks in advance!

Solved : This is the code i used.

```
 node_ids = [search_node_id,parent1_node_id,parent2_node_id]

 function select_node(node_ids,length,evt,e){
 var node=leftnav_treePanel.getNodeById(node_ids[length]); //length is length of node_ids list
 var ajaxReq = ajaxRequest(node.attributes.url,0,"GET",true);
 ajaxReq.request({
     success: function(xhr) {
        var response=Ext.util.JSON.decode(xhr.responseText);
        if(length>0){
            removeChild(node); // method to remove existing childnodes
            appendChild(response.nodes,node); // method to add child nodes from response
            node.expand();
            select_node(node_ids,length-1,evt,e);
        }else{
           node.fireEvent(evt,node,e);
        }
            },
     failure: function(xhr){
            Ext.MessageBox.alert( _("Failure") , xhr.statusText);
     }
 });
```

}

Comment: Please provide code...

Answer (score 0):

Taking a wild guess at what's going on here because you have not provided any code.  I think that you have an asynchronously loading treestore through ajax and that the nodes in the store have not yet been loaded to the users page, which is why javascript is unable to find them.

Comment: oh.thanks for the reply. Now i am phrasing the search node path from python. so now i have path to the node like this : root_node_id/node_id/child_node_id. Now, do i have to expand with each node id in the path hierarchy..? or is there any other way....?

Comment: tree.expandPath(path, null, function(success ){ alert(success) });   returns false :(. expand on each id is the only solution i guess.

Comment: Provide code exampes or a jsFiddle if you want more help.  I can't tell you what's wrong without more info.

Comment: Thanks, for your response. i have solved and i have attached the code above